# Safely using eval to calculate using the math module in python

Tags: python, eval

I want to get a calculation result from a user-inputted string, while using `math` functions such as `sin` or `ceil`. I also would like to be able to do it as `sin(30)`, not `math.sin(30)`. I thought doing

```
from math import *
```

would work, because when I import all, it shows as a built-in function, and built-in functions are imported. However, when I ran the code, it showed that the math functions didn't work inside `eval()`

```
>>> from math import *
>>> sin
<built-in function sin>
>>> print
<built-in function print>
>>> eval("sin(30)", {}, {})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    eval("sin(30)", {}, {})
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sin' is not defined
```

Would I have to add in all of the math functions manually, or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: You explicitly ran `eval` with empty local and global namespaces.

Comment: in addition to the above, nothing about what you are doing is safer than any other use of  eval. Not sure what the `safely` in the title is referring to.

Comment: "when I import all, it shows as a built-in function, and built-in functions are imported" - the "built-in" in "built-in function sin" means it's written in C. This is completely unrelated to whether it's available in the built-ins namespace. Unfortunately, "built-in" means multiple unrelated things in Python. (Also, the mechanism that makes built-in names automatically available has nothing to do with imports.)

Comment: Even with empty namespaces, malicious code can do stuff like `().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()[-1].__init__.__globals__['__builtins__']['__import__']('os').system('install ransomware or something')` to run arbitrary shell commands and do horrible things. `eval` is fundamentally the wrong tool for this. It's convenient, but wrong.

Comment: @HansMusgrave - `eval` is for expressions. The `while` will raise a syntax error. Of course you can make evil list comprehensions, and etc...

Comment: @HansMusgrave - Which got me thinking about how to turn eval evil. Turns out it was easy: `eval("""list(map(__import__("os").__dict__["remove"], ["aaa"]))""", {}, {})`. Since these names aren't in either the globals or locals I supplied, I'm not sure why this works.

Comment: @tdelaney: If `__builtins__` isn't present in the provided globals, `eval` gives the evaluated code default builtins. Even if you explicitly give the code empty `__builtins__`, though, something like my comment still works, since that doesn't even rely on built-in names being available.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - Yeah, I don't see any way around it. Maybe there is a python based math DSL (domain specific language) already out there somewhere.

Comment: **Absolutely 100% do not put user input into the eval function.**

Comment: @tdelaney That looks delightful. Also, the simpleeval package looks like a possible solution. I haven't given it enough due diligence to definitely recommend it, but it's purpose is to allow restricted expression evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding "safely", it depends on what you mean.  You can provide access to your global environment easily enough, giving the expression access to whatever you've imported.  But there is nothing to stop a user from entering an expression that can do unintended things, so if the expression is coming from an untrusted user, then you should avoid the use of `eval`.

That having been said, you can make your example work as follows:

```
>>> from math import *
>>> eval("sin(30)", globals())
-0.9880316240928618
>>>
```

Note that in this example, `30` is being interpreted as radians rather than degrees.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo -e  'import math\nmathok={k: v for k, v in math.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith("__")}\nprint(eval("3*pi",{"__builtins__": {}},mathok))' | python               
9.42477796076938
```

Comment: As for all the other answers and comments on this page - OMG - why do people who have no idea about a topic insist on posting their wrong opinions.  eva() in python **is** SPECIFICALLY designed to be safe when you use it properly.